# How to combine OpenCV with PyQt to create a simple GUI?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, pyqt4

I need to perform lot of operations on an image. So I used OpenCV. OpenCV is very efficient in image processing, however it is not too good to present a suitable GUI. So I decided to use PyQt to draw a custom GUI and OpenCV to process my image.

I created a very simple program you directly picked from the documentation. I simply read a `jpg` picture and save it in a `png` format by pressing the key `s`.

My aim is to replace the key `s` with a button to press to perform the same action using PyQt. Also, I want the window displayed by PyQt to have the same behavior as OpenCV: mainly speaking, the function `imshow()` displays a window that fits to the image size.

Here is my OpenCV simple code:

```
import numpy 
import cv2

class LoadImage:
    def loadImage(self):
        img = cv2.imread('photo.jpg')
        cv2.imshow('Image on a window',img)
        k = cv2.waitKey(0)
        if k == 27:
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        elif k == ord('s'):
            cv2.imwrite('photopng.png',img)
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__=="__main__":
    LI=LoadImage()
    LI.loadImage()
```

Output:

[image]

Here is a simple PyQt code to draw a simple window:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class DrawWindow:
    def drawWindow(self):
        app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        w=QtGui.QWidget()
        #w.resize(250,250)
        w.move(300,300)
        w.setWindowTitle("Simple Window")
        w.show()

        sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__=="__main__":
    DW=DrawWindow()
    DW.drawWindow()
```

How can I mix the 2 codes to reach my goal?

Answer (score 13):

Modified some code basing on your post, I didn't use the Opencv to render the image, instead using QPixmap to render it. then use KeyPressEvent to capture the user input .

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import numpy
import cv2
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *


class MyDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        self.cvImage = cv2.imread(r'cat.jpg')
        height, width, byteValue = self.cvImage.shape
        byteValue = byteValue * width

        cv2.cvtColor(self.cvImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB, self.cvImage)

        self.mQImage = QImage(self.cvImage, width, height, byteValue, QImage.Format_RGB888)

    def paintEvent(self, QPaintEvent):
        painter = QPainter()
        painter.begin(self)
        painter.drawImage(0, 0, self.mQImage)
        painter.end()

    def keyPressEvent(self, QKeyEvent):
        super(MyDialog, self).keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent)
        if 's' == QKeyEvent.text():
            cv2.imwrite("cat2.png", self.cvImage)
        else:
            app.exit(1)


if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyDialog()
    w.resize(600, 400)
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thank you for trying. First, I really need to use OpenCV for image processing. Second, I got several errors when compiled your code. +1 however for the effort.

Comment: This Code seems correct. The processing is in OpenCV (e.g. look at cv2.cvtColor) and only the displaying is handled using Qt (QPixmap) which is fine. I am doing the same in a lot off scripts. Be carefull though when converting your image from cv to qt (search the web for converters)!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `QImage` directly from the image data read by OpenCV, convert that to a `QPixmap` using `QPixmap.fromImage` and then use that to set the pixmap of a `QLabel` using the `setPixmap` method.

This page shows how to view a webcam feed by using PySide and OpenVC: https://gist.github.com/bsdnoobz/8464000. I made it work for videos as well, by commenting out these two lines

```
self.capture.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, self.video_size.width())
self.capture.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, self.video_size.height())
```

and instead using

```
resized_bgr_frame = cv2.resize(
    bgr_frame,
    (self.video_size.width(), self.video_size.height()),
    interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC if self.video_size.width() > bgr_frame.shape[1] else cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

on the video frame (where `bgr_frame` is the frame that was obtained with `self.capture.read()`).

(Note that there is some different naming and namespace conventions for the OpenCV constants going on here, perhaps due to differing `cv2` versions?)