# How to convert between QT-QColor with opencv-cv::Scalar?

Tags: qt, opencv, qcolor

I am using `opencv+Qt(c++)` and I want convert a `QColor RGB` pixel to an `opencv BGR` pixel:

```
QColor --> cv::Scalar
cv::Scalar --> QColor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

qcolor --> scalar

```
cv::Scalar qcolor2scalar(QColor color)
{
    int r,g,b;
    color.getRgb(&r, &g, &b);
    return cv::Scalar(b,g,r); // swap RGB-->BGR
}
```

scalar --> qcolor

```
QColor scalar2qcolor(cv::Scalar color)
{
    return QColor(color[2],color[1],color[0]); // swap RGB-->BGR
}
```

Comment: You probably want to swap B and R, since in OpenCV you usually work on BGR, while in Qt in RGB. Also you should use the qreal variant, `getRgbF`, since Scalar contains doubles

Answer (score 1):

You have not given a programming language. In python, you can use commands such as:

```
cv2image=cv2.cvtColor(cv2image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
cv2image=cv2.cvtColor(cv2image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
cv2image=cv2.cvtColor(cv2image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
```

For C++ the commands are similar.

You may also want to have a look here: [How to combine OpenCV with PyQt to create a simple GUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28282434/how-to-combine-opencv-with-pyqt-to-create-a-simple-gui)